# How to add boto3 AWS S3 object tags in FME?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, tags, boto3, fme

new to coding and researching a work project. There are many files stored in S3 buckets that are processed by FME automations. I want to be able to add S3 object tagging to my FME transformers so they are uploaded with the appropriate tags. I found some stuff about adding tags to buckets but I want to tag individual objects, with a Python caller or custom transformer in FME. Any guidance?

Comment: It's recommended to included examples of what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boto3 and AWS CLI support object upload with tagging.
An example would be (for boto3):

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

client.put_object(
    Bucket='bucket', 
    Key='key',
    Body='bytes', 
    Tagging='Key1=Value1'
)
```

I looked at the FME S3 Connector docs (http://docs.safe.com/fme/2020.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/s3connector.htm)
and they only support metadata upload.

You could use user-defined metadata key-pairs as an option if you need to use the FME transformers.

S3 Metadata: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html